# How do I fix a SSL Certificate error when using a get()?

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I am running a requests line like the following:

```py
reqs = requests.get('http://test.com')
```

I am being returned the following error:

```py
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='test.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?q=test.org (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

I have tried the following:

```bash
pip install python-certifi-win32
pip install --upgrade certifi
```

And neither seem to work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you trying this on a local machine? Might need to stick this at the top of your .py:

"os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = '127.0.0.1'"

Comment: When sending a request on the same host use `verify=False`. Try `requests.get('http://test.com', verify=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, recreating here as the syntax in the comments is always hard to read.

I've found for the requests library, when testing on the local machine I need to put this at top of file:

```
import os  # Obviously!

os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = '127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: Why would this have any effect on the problem?

Comment: Not sure - but its certainly affected me when trying to get python requests to talk to other things on my PC (for testing obviously).

Dunno whether its the OPs issue or not, they haven't returned with feedback. Artyom's recommendation is indeed 100% valid. But in the past, that alone didn't rectify the issue I had.

Comment: I don't any evidence that the problem is caused when trying to connect to same host.

Comment: Nor is there any evidence it is not. Better for me to suggest it and have Astro read it, then dismiss it as not relevant to them than for me to horde the info and leave Astro searching for a solution. After all, that is the reason for stackoverflow is it not? Suggest solutions to problems...